Alpine.js: 'fruit is not defined' error when using x-sort directive in Chrome's Dev Tools device mode
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Alpine Plugins -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@alpinejs/sort@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- Alpine Core -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul x-data="{ fruits:['durians','apples','oranges'] }" x-sort>
        <template x-for="fruit in fruits">
            <li  x-text="fruit" x-sort:item></li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

The code above works well when I'm just running it normally on my computer. However, I get a fruit is not defined error when I try to drag any of the items in Chrome's Dev Tools device mode. How can I solve my problem?

Your code works fine, no errors - at least, not in Firefox

Everything is ok with Chrome too: is this the real code or just an excerpt?

@TUPKAP This is the real code.

Ok after the clarification that the problem occurs in 'mobile' mode, I've tested the code with Chrome in 'device mode' and with Firefox in 'responsive mode' and now I get the same error in console. Perhaps an issue should be opened on Github in the AlpineJs repository.

Ok, so I finally found the solution. The solution is to just add x-bind:x-ignore="true" to the li. I'm not sure why it works though.
